# python sort 2D dictionary by index

Tags: python, sorting

I have a 2D dictionary as follows

```
    dict =  {'182.12.17.50': {'185.23.15.69': 30, '175.12.13.14': 14}, '182.15.12.30': {'175.12.13.15': 10, '145.33.34.56': 230}}
```

I want to sort that based on the value such that the out put looks like

```
  [{IP1: '182.15.12.30', IP2: '175.12.13.15', val:10}, {IP1: '182.12.17.50', IP2: '175.12.13.14', val:14}, ...]
```

I am a newbie in python. I have written an ugly code for that. Is there any nice way to implement that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and the built-in [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
sorted(({'IP1': ip1, 'IP2': k, 'val':v}
           for ip1,subdct in dct.items()
           for k,v in subdct.items()),
       key=lambda newd: newd['val'])
```

By the way, it's a bad idea to use `dict` as the name of a variable, as doing so overshadows the built-in [dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict). Therefore, I renamed the variable to `dct`.